# Finding where Story Map is stored

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

About 3-5 years ago I created a Story Map using the Map Journal template.

That Story Map is still available at https://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=163b6d4177354fbb93ba9ed4aedd8ee3

However, I now want to review/update it to comply with [FAQ: What do I need to know about HTTPS Only and the ArcGIS Platform?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022877) and I have not been able to locate where it is stored.

I thought that I would be able to go to ArcGIS.com, login using my Esri Global Account, and see it in my Gallery.  However, it does not appear to be there.

Is there a way to use the URL of a Story Map to find out where it is stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the id in your url to find it (**163b6d4177354fbb93ba9ed4aedd8ee3**)

Process

- Build the item detail page url by using the following model :

  ```
  https://[my_organisation_tag].maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=[item_id]
  ```
- When you see the detail page of your storymap, the location of the item should be displayed on the right panel under the "FOLDER" title.

For example, if your organisation is polygeo :

```
https://polygeo.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=163b6d4177354fbb93ba9ed4aedd8ee3
```